# atk4 database table id

Tags: mysql, database, orm, model, atk4

i've a question about atk4 MVCgrid, my db table doesn't have a field called "id" my primary key is id_material, i don't be able to change idfield, my SQL contain a file id that doesnt' exist so it fail.
How i can change default id primary key field (id) with my real primary key?

My simple code:

```
class Model_Material  extends Model_Table 
{
    public $entity_code='material';
    public $table_alias='p';
    function defineFields(){
        parent::defineFields();
        $this->addField('id_material');
        $this->addField('material');
    }
}
```

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to create an alias:

```
$this->getField('id')->calculated(true);

function calculate_id(){
    return 'id_material';
}
```

You would have more difficulties with foreign keys. You might want to keep watch on 4.2 release, which will have more flexibility.

- https://github.com/atk4/atk4/commits/4.2
- https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/4.2/lib/Model/Field/Reference.php

Comment: Thank's a lot,but for me it's strange that is not possible to set default table primary key by simple parameter, why default choice is always "id"?, i've see that "setsource" have a second parameter, maybe i can set an array of may database field directly there? excuse but form me is a new approch

Comment: You can set static array of data through `setStaticSource`. The reason why we need "id" for the grid is because our JavaScript bindings assume to have a column they can rely as unique identifier and what's better name for ID field then "id" ?